# Is there a decorator for .net data providers that don't support named SQL parameters?

Tags: sql, .net, ado.net, sqlparameter

I want to allow my users to connect to a database in different ways:

- either with a DB-specific ADO.NET provider, like e.g. MySqlConnector or Npgsql
- or by creating a DSN on Windows and then using the types in the `System.Data.Odbc` namespace to use the database

The latter would be very useful for reasons of backwards compatibility.

In my code, I use the abstract types. In principle, I should be able to use the exact same SQL statements, regardless of which way to connect my customers choose.

Now the problem I face has to do with *named* SQL parameters (not only positional parameters). Using ODBC, I didn't find a way to use them, e.g. in a query like

```sql
SELECT alpha, beta
FROM gamma
WHERE delta = @epsilon
```

In some SQL dialects ':' instead of '@' is used to prefix parameters, but that is not the issue here. System.Data.Odbc doesn't seem to pass the (named) parameters whatsoever.

Does there already exist some wrapper around System.Data.Odbc that enables using SQL parameters? Some kind of decorator for System.Data?

Comment: Note that your example tries to use a parameter as a *column name* which isn't supported by many databases regardless of ODBC or not. Did you mean `WHERE epsilon = @delta`? That would be a more realistic example of *normal* parameter usage.

Comment: But the ODBC provider supports parameters - just not *named* parameters. I'd expect `WHERE epsilon = ?` to work fine.

Comment: In several ODBC scenarios, parameters are anonymous and positional - i.e. `where Foo = ?` would mean "bind to the next parameter" (each successive `?` meaning the next, if you see what I mean; to borrow an example from MSDN: `INSERT INTO Parts (PartID, Description, Price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)` binds to 3 successive parameters); are you sure that isn't available? but to answer the explicit question: no, I'm not aware of a decorator that would rewrite that for you

Comment: @JonSkeet and MarcGravell, thank you for pointing out my mistakes in the question. I stand corrected. The question is rather whether something already exists to use named instead of positional parameters.

Comment: @pvoosten are you aware of any provider that doesn't support parameters? Both ODBC and OLEDDB have parameters, and by extension so does ADO.NET.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the question is rather how *named* parameters instead of *positional* parameters can be used.

Comment: @pvoosten edit the question to say that. Right now it asks something completely different, in a rather roundabout way

Comment: @pvoosten: I'd argue that's still a *very* unusual use of a parameter, and almost never what's intended. Whereas I've seen lots of examples of people trying to do that, specifying a column name as a parameter, and it failing. (I suspect even if it's theoretically valid in those cases, it fails in most databases.) It's at best a questionable choice of example, IMO.

Comment: `:` is the ANSI SQL way (for static Embedded SQL. Dynamic has `?`.)

Comment: All right @JonSkeet, I edited the example, and am now waiting for someone to answer the question.

Comment: At this point, it feels like it's really a request for a tool or other resource - but fundamentally, I wouldn't really expect there to be anything to provide named parameters as a facade over technology that only supports positional parameters.